# Ignore URL from Highlight the search text

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have a javascript like:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function getHighlight() {
            var MainText = '';
            var toSearch = 'store';
            MainText = MainText + '<table>';
            MainText = MainText + '<tr><td><b>Stores</b></td></tr>';
            MainText = MainText + '<tr><td class="clsUrl"><a href="check%20Store%20quality.aspx" style="color:blue; text-decoration:none;" target="_blank">check%20Store%20quality.aspx</a></td></tr>';
            MainText = MainText + '<tr><td><p>Some Description about store...</p><br /></td></tr>';
            MainText = MainText + '</table>';
            $('.dv_searchResult').append(MainText);
            textHightLight($(".dv_searchResult").html(), toSearch, ".dv_searchResult");
       }

    function textHightLight(totText, term, dvCls) {
        var src_str = totText;

        term = term.replace(/(\s+)/, "(<[^>]+>)*$1(<[^>]+>)*");
        var pattern = new RegExp("(" + term + ")", "gi");

        src_str = src_str.replace(pattern, "<mark>$1</mark>");
        src_str = src_str.replace(/(<mark>[^<>]*)((<[^>]+>)+)([^<>]*<\/mark>)/, "$1</mark>$2<mark>$4");

        $(dvCls).html(src_str);
    }
        </script>
```

Here I am binding the complete html into a div `dv_searchResult` and then highlighting the `toSearch` text inside the div.
Its working fine to an extent. The only problem is that if the `toSearch` text contains any word which exists also in url (eg, in the above text, `store` exists inside `href="check%20Store%20quality.aspx"` also.),then the url is also replaced with `<mark></mark>` that i am using to highlight the word.
I need help on how can I ignore the `clsUrl` class or the `<a href="">` tag while reading the text in `textHightLight function`.

See the example here: https://jsfiddle.net/3jfs1kum/

Kindly help.

Comment: can you provide a fiddle??

Comment: @GuruprasadRao i have added the fiddle. kindly check

Comment: so you want to avoid only href of `a` or complete `a` tag??

Comment: I am looking to avoid complete 'a' tag. but any one the 2 will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok after much research, I've got one solution for your problem:

```
$('input[type=submit]').click( function() {
 var MainText = '';
            var toSearch = 'store';
            MainText = MainText + '<table>';
            MainText = MainText + '<tr><td><b>Stores</b></td></tr>';
            MainText = MainText + '<tr><td class="clsUrl"><a href="check%20Store%20quality.aspx" style="color:blue; text-decoration:none;" target="_blank">check%20Store%20quality.aspx</a></td></tr>';
            MainText = MainText + '<tr><td><p>Some Description about store...</p><br /></td></tr>';
            MainText = MainText + '</table>';
            $('.dv_searchResult').append(MainText);
            textHightLight($(".dv_searchResult"), toSearch, ".dv_searchResult");
            //instead of sending html to textHightLight function just send the whole element  
});
function textHightLight(totText, term, dvCls) {

        a=$(totText).find('a').detach();//Just detach anchor tag from table for time being and keep a copy of it to attach it back on later part.
        var src_str = $(totText).html();//Once done take the html and start searching
        var childNodes = document.body.childNodes;
        term = term.replace(/(\s+)/, "(<[^>]+>)*$1(<[^>]+>)*");
        var pattern = new RegExp("(" + term + ")", "gi");

        src_str = src_str.replace(pattern, "<mark>$1</mark>");

        src_str = src_str.replace(/(<mark>[^<>]*)((<[^>]+>)+)([^<>]*<\/mark>)/, "$1</mark>$2<mark>$4");

        $(dvCls).html(src_str);
    if(a)//Once search is done attach the particular tag back to the place where it was.
         //If you don't want to display it in result just comment this part of code from if
        {
            $('.clsUrl').append(a);
         }//till here
    }
```

Here is the **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3jfs1kum/5/)**

**Note**: This solution is given considering there will be only 1 `anchor` tag in a table. If you have multiple anchor tags to avoid in search then you need to detach whole `td` which has particular class and then attach it back after the first `td` element of a particular row. [you can drop a comment if this is the requirement]

**EDIT - 1**: So the below solution looks more better than what I suggested previously and it will not detach any elements but just filters the `a` tag from each `td` of the `table` and gives you the search result. Take a look

```
function textHightLight(totText, term, dvCls) {
        var clas=$(totText).attr('class');
        var elem=$('div.'+clas+' table tr td:not(:has(a))');
        var src_str = "";
        $.each(elem,function(index,value){
            src_str+=$(value).html();
        });
        term = term.replace(/(\s+)/, "(<[^>]+>)*$1(<[^>]+>)*");
        var pattern = new RegExp("(" + term + ")", "gi");

        src_str = src_str.replace(pattern, "<mark>$1</mark>");

        src_str = src_str.replace(/(<mark>[^<>]*)((<[^>]+>)+)([^<>]*<\/mark>)/, "$1</mark>$2<mark>$4");

        $(dvCls).html(src_str);
}
```

and here is the **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3jfs1kum/4/)**

Comment: thank @Guruprasad Rao ...worked like a charm. exactly what i needed. :)

Comment: My pleasure. I got more interesting about this and I've edited my answer which I feel is a better way to do. Take a look.. :) Happy Coding.. :)